# d3.js tooltip display "[object Promise]" instead of value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, promise, tooltip

I try to display with d3.js, in a tooltip, the value returned by an asynchronous function. The value is well returned by the function but when I have to show the tooltip, it contains [object Promise] instead of the value.

I use async/await to work with asynchronous functions like this :

Create the data which the tooltip will contain :

```
async function jsonMethodsArray(d) {
var arr = [];
// $.getJSON is asynchronous
// so wait until the end of its execution before proceeding to the other instructions
var json = await $.getJSON("method/data" + d.id + ".json", function(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.nodes.length - 1; i++) {
        var node = json.nodes[i+1];
        arr.push(node.id);
    }
});
return arr;
}
```

Create and call the tooltip :

```
var tooltip = d3.tip()
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.offset([-8, 0])
.html(async function(d) {
    // jsonMethodsArray is asynchronous due to $.getJSON
    // so wait until the end of its execution before proceeding to the other instructions
    var methods = await jsonMethodsArray(d);
    console.log(methods);
    return methods.join("\n");
});
svg.call(tooltip);
```

Show or hide the tooltip :

```
.on('mouseover', tooltip.show)
.on('mouseout', tooltip.hide)
```

Instead of display the values of the array returned in the tooltip, it display [object Promise].

I am a beginner with Javascript, d3.js and asynchronous functions, can you help me ?

Comment: Can you explain why you use async calls when you are asking for sync. operation on mouse over? Most likely that promise is not ready by the time you perform ```tooltip.show```

Comment: @Mulli I use async calls because $.getJSON is async so to get data from the json I have to use async and await otherwise I don’t have access to the right values on time. I don't know how to work with tooltip.show after the result of the promise.

Comment: I would try pre-loading the tooltip to verify that ```toolip.show``` is ok.

Comment: And how can I do that ? @Mulli

Comment: Please look at the following link https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_tooltip.html
Following those example, you get the tooltip content into a variable at initialization. Perform: ```var methods = await jsonMethodsArray(d);``` at start/

Later attach ```methods``` to a tooltip element.

Comment: @Mulli thank you for your help. I follow your link and I change the way I get data from the json and it works.

Comment: Nhuyen. I am glad. Please mark my answer as correct answer to your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the following link [d3 documentation](http://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_tooltip.html) Following those examples, you get the tooltip content into a variable at initialization.

Perform: `var methods = await jsonMethodsArray(d);` at start.

Later attach methods to a tooltip element